# How To Fade Then Refade jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.titleword').fadeOut(500 , function(){
    $('.titleword').click(function(){
                var str = $(this).text();
                var idx;
                for (var x=0;x<5;x++)
                {
                    if (str == categories[x])
                    {
                        idx = x;
                    }
                }
                categories[idx] = $('#headertext').text();
                $('#headertext').text(str)
                $(this).text(categories[idx]);
     });
     $('.titleword').fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});
```

nw i'm fading out this class then do someoperation, what i need is to fadein again after this operation.

but what've done is just fading out only, without fading in

how can i do both operations ?????

Comment: why are you setting click handler inside fadeOut() callback?

Comment: to fadeOut when i click on some object , then automatically fadeTo after some operations !

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('.titleword').fadeOut(500 , function(){
    $('.titleword').click(function(){
                var str = $(this).text();
                var idx;
                for (var x=0;x<5;x++)
                {
                    if (str == categories[x])
                    {
                        idx = x;
                    }
                }
                categories[idx] = $('#headertext').text();
                $('#headertext').text(str)
                $(this).text(categories[idx]);
                $('.titleword').fadeTo(500,1); //add this here

     });
     $('.titleword').fadeTo(500,1);
    });
```

Comment: basically, this will just `fadeTo(500,1)`

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.titleword').click(function(){
            var str = $(this).text();
            var idx;
            for (var x=0;x<5;x++)
            {
                if (str == categories[x])
                {
                    idx = x;
                }
            }
            categories[idx] = $('#headertext').text();
            $('#headertext').text(str)
            $(this).text(categories[idx]);
     });

     $('.titleword').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Because binding the click inside the fading doesn't make sense to me. Then the fadeout/in comes straightforward.

Cheers